# Extended Conformal Thin-sandwich Method

Tags: general-relativity, differential-geometry

I got a question about the following [lecture notes](https://arxiv.org/abs/gr-qc/0703035) by Eric Gourgoulhon .

My question concerns equation (8.95), page 141:
$$    \tilde{D}_i \tilde{D}^i N + 2\tilde{D}_i \log\Psi \tilde{D}^i N = \Psi^{-1}\left(\tilde{D}_i\tilde{D}^i\left(N\Psi\right) + N \tilde{D}_i\tilde{D}^i\Psi \right) \, .$$ I'm not able to prove this identity. By working both sides out, I reduced the problem to
$$    \tilde{D}_i \Psi \tilde{D}^i N = N \tilde{D}_i \tilde{D}^i \Psi \, ,$$
but I don't see why this is true. Intuitively, I can see why this is true when there is a minus sign (I see it then when integrated over, as partial integration where the boundary terms are zero). Moreover, if there is a minus sign, the next equation (8.96) should also work out which, right now does not work out when I work it out.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: you may also want to look at Eric Gourgoulhon's book on numerical relativity

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I also think it's a typo; See the third page of the [errata](https://relativite.obspm.fr/3p1/errata.pdf).

LHS is:
$$ \tilde{D}^{i}\tilde{D}_{i}N + 2 \tilde{D}_{i}\log\Psi \tilde{D}^{i}N=\\
\color{red}{\tilde{D}^{i}\tilde{D}_{i}N} + \color{orange}{\frac{2}{\Psi} \tilde{D}_{i}\Psi \tilde{D}^{i}N}$$

Meanwhile, RHS is:

$$\Psi^{-1}\big{[}\tilde{D}^{i}\tilde{D}_{i}(N\Psi) \color{blue}{-} N \tilde{D}^{i}\tilde{D}_{i}\Psi \big{]} = \\
\Psi^{-1}\big{[}\tilde{D}^{i}(\tilde{D}_{i}N \cdot\;\Psi + \tilde{D}_{i}\Psi \cdot \; N) + N \tilde{D}^{i}\tilde{D}_{i}\Psi \big{]} = \\ 
\color{red}{\Psi^{-1}\tilde{D}^{i}\tilde{D}_{i}N \; \cdot\Psi} + \color{orange}{\Psi^{-1}\tilde{D}_{i}N\tilde{D}^{i}\Psi} + \Psi^{-1}\tilde{D}^{i}\tilde{D}_{i}\Psi\cdot\;N  + \color{orange}{\Psi^{-1}\tilde{D}^{i}N\tilde{D}_{i}\Psi} \color{blue}{-} \Psi^{-1}N \tilde{D}^{i}\tilde{D}_{i}\Psi$$

So that the term with the full trace of conformal second derivative of $\Psi$ cancels.